# How do I attach more than one photo to a single email sent on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, photos, attachments

There doesn't seem to be a way to attach photos to an email in the Mail app on the iPhone.  I can send photos from the Camera Roll in the Photos app, but I can only attach one photo per email?  Is there a trick I'm missing?  Or is there an app for that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OS 3.0 and above allows you to email out up to 5 photos.

- Go to your Camera roll. Select the roll you want.
- Tap Share icon (bottom left)
- Tap each photo you want to send via e-mail ( you should get a red check mark in each photo > Share count will increase to the number of photos selected).
- Tap "Share Icon" again
- A pop up "e-mail" message will appear
- All the photos you selected will appear in your e-mail message to send.

Comment: Just as an aside, you can also copy-and-paste photos - thus allowing you to circumvent the 5 photos limit. Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way for attaching more than one photo is:

- Tap the edit button in photo app
- Tap the photos you want to attach
- Tap copy button on your screen or in sharing options
- Then go to e-mail app, hold your finger on the screen and choose paste command

Answer (score 0):

When you have the photo app open after you click attach file from email, Click the "share and command"buttons  at the same time! Then you will have the option to attac more that one picture. I just did it a second ago! It worked!!!!!